# I create button to print specific area of web page but CSS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, printing, bootstrap-4

I create button to print specific area of web page but CSS doesn't work, how can I solve this problem ?

I tried to use @media print but also not work

This is the bootstrap, style and js code

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```css
.printme {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .no-printme {
    display: none;
  }
  .printme {
    display: block;
  }
  .h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  div.container {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block content-block-horizantal printarea">
  <div class="content-block-ttl">Eye History</div>
  <div class="content-block-main text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Auto Refractometer</h2>
      <p>Here you can record auto refreactometer values and notes</p>
      <div class="row content-input">
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
          <h2>Right Eye</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
          <h2>left Eye</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row content-input">
        <!-- Right Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 ">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">SP1</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="sp1" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">CY1</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="CY1" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">AXIS</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="AXIS" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
        <!-- Left Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">SP1</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="sp1" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">CY1</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="CY1" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
          <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">AXIS</label>
          <input class="form-input" placeholder="AXIS" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Eyee Notes -->
      <div class="row content-input">
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
          <textarea class="form-input" placeholder="Notes" type="textarea" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
          <textarea class="form-input" placeholder="Notes" type="textarea" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Glass Prescription -->
    <div class="container" id='printMe' style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">
      <h2>Glass Prescription</h2>
      <p>Here you can write glass prescription</p>
      <div class="row content-input">
        <div class="col-sm-2" align="center"> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5" align="center">
          <h2>Right Eye</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5" align="center">
          <h2>left Eye</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row content-input">
        <!-- Right Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 "> </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">SP1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">CY1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">AXIS</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">VISION</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left Eyee -->
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">SP1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">CY1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">AXIS</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <label style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">VISION</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Dist. -->
      <div class="row content-input">
        <!-- Right Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 ">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">Dist.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left Eyee -->
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Near -->
      <div class="row content-input">
        <!-- Right Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 ">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">Near</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left Eyee -->
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Computer -->
      <div class="row content-input">
        <!-- Right Eyee -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 ">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">Computer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left Eyee -->
        <div class="row col-sm-5">
          <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="printDiv('printMe')">Print only the above div</button>
```

I used this code to print specific div on my code but the print neglect the css of the div so I used @media print but also the same problem
You can check the difference between the html website view and print result from this : 
[The website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwKto.png)
[The print preview, you can find style isn't applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtOsF.png)

what can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: there's no elements with class `no-printme` and no elements with class `printme`

Comment: @CalvinNunes , I have     <div class="container" id='printMe' style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;"> , must I add printme to class of the div ?

Comment: If you want that div to respect what is setted on the css class `.printme`, so of course, you need